# Is there an easy way to check if a specific data extension is used in journey builder, automation or trigger?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm looking to locate where a specific data extension is use in SFMC as I need to compile a list of journey, automation and trigger that is leveraging this DE. I don't want to have to manually open up all the journey or automation and dig into each one to see which DE it's using. Any idea if it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific guideline on how to proceed in your case and it highly dependant on how many Journeys, Automations or Triggered DEs you have and thus you would need to check.

The problem here is that each "usage" type of Data Extension would require you to prepare a separate approach to see the result, for example:

1. To get Data Extensions used as an Entry Source in the Journeys you can use this [endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm) where you would specify each time different Journey name or you can create a loop with SSJS. In the response body, you would receive desired `dataExtensionName` and more.

```
https://[your_rest_subdomain]/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/?name=[your_journey_name]
```

2. To get Data Extensions used in Query and Import Activities in Automation Studio there is a good [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/05/20/inventory-of-data-extensions-and-their-data-sources/) prepared by Zuzanna Jarczynska that will give you an idea on that.